# Getting HTML-Values in a QGIS-form by pyQT5

Tags: qgis-3, pyqt5

I have created a form for point-objects, that is delivering some values (getting by a database-connection) in the "html-area" in the form.

[image: HTML-Code in a QGIS-form]

So far the form works well and I´m getting the values that I need:

[image: DElivering values in the html-section]

But since hours I try to get these values by PyQT5.

No problem to get the "NON"-HTMl-values like:

```
bottom_elevation = myDialog.findChild(QDoubleSpinBox, "BOTTOM_ELEVATION")
```

But how can I get by Python the entries in the html-section?